# How to find files with specific pattern in directory with specific number? Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got folders named folder1 all the way up to folder150 and maybe beyond.. but I only want to find the complete path to text files in some of the folders (for example folder1 to folder50).

I thought a command like the following might work, but it is incorrect.

```
find '/path/to/directory/folder{1..50}' -name '*.txt'
```

The solution doesn't have to use find, as long as it does the correct thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /path/to/directory/folder{1..50} -name '*.txt'  2>/dev/null
```

Or only basename

```
find /path/to/directory/folder{1..50} -name '*.txt' -exec basename {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Or basename without .txt

```
 find /path/to/directory/folder{1..50} -name '*.txt' -exec basename {} .txt \; 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

[V. Michel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5374489/v-michel) directly solves your problem; to complement it with an *explanation*:

Bash's [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) is only applied to *unquoted* strings; your solution attempt uses a *single-quoted* string, whose contents are by definition interpreted as *literals*.

Contrast the following two statements:

```
# WRONG:
# {...} inside a single-quoted (or double-quoted) string: interpreted as *literal*.
echo 'folder{1..3}' # -> 'folder{1..3}'

# OK:
# Unquoted use of {...} -> *brace expansion* is applied.
echo 'folder'{1..3} # -> 'folder1 folder2 folder 3'
```

Note how only the brace expression is left unquoted in the 2nd example above, which demonstrates that you can selectively mix quoted and unquoted substrings in Bash.

---

It is worth noting that it is - and can only be - *Bash* that performs brace expansion here, and `find` only sees the resulting, *literal* paths.<sup>[1]</sup>

`find` only accepts *literal* paths as filename operands.
(Some of `find`'s primaries (tests), such as `-name` and `-path`, do support *globs* (as demonstrated in the question), but not brace expansion; to ensure that such globs are passed through intact to `find`, without premature expansion by Bash, they must be *quoted*; e.g., `-name '*.txt'`)

---

<sup>[1] After Bash performs brace expansion, *globbing* (pathname expansion) may occur *in addition*, as demonstrated in [ehaymore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206234/45375); `folder(?,[1-4]?,50)` is brace-expanded to tokens `folder?`, `folder[1-4]?`, and `folder50`, the first two of which are subject to globbing, due to containing pattern metacharacters (`?`, `[...]`). Whether globbing is involved or not, the target program ultimately only sees the resulting *literal* paths.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can give multiple directories to the find command, each matching part of the pattern you're looking for. For example,

```
find /path/to/directory/folder{?,[1-4]?,50} -name '*.txt'
```

which expands to three patterns:

- folder? (matches 0-9)
- folder[1-4]? (matches 10-49)
- folder50

The question mark is a single-character wildcard.

Comment: The `[-4]?` in `folder[1-4]?` will not just match `10` through `49`, but _any_ two-character sequence whose first characters is `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`, including, for  instance, `1a`; similarly, `?` will match _any_ single character. You're correct that `find` accepts multiple file/folder operands, but there is no reason to alter the OP's brace expression, which works perfectly fine once you use it _unquoted_, in which case it will expand _unambiguously_ to the desired multiple arguments:  `.../folder1`, `.../folder2`, ..., `folder50`.

Comment: All true. However, a sequential set of folders was given only as an example way of subsetting the list, and this method will generalize better to other subsets.

Comment: The OP's question was about a specific brace expression - `{1..50}` - that they couldn't get to work.
The only problem was the use of that expression inside a quoted string.
You answer (a) doesn't point that out, (b) offers a _different_ brace expression that is _more permissive_ than the OP's, without stating so.
While combining the _list_ form of brace expansion with _globs_, as you do here, may be interesting in general, _here_ it is a _distraction_.

Comment: I've deleted one of my comments and instead added more background information to my answer, including mentioning your technique (with a link to your answer), but note that I've placed it in a _footnote_, where I think it belongs in the context of this question.